# How to create a Singleton WCF proxy using Structuremap

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, structuremap

> In WCF, creating a proxy is a heavy operation, so if you are experiencing performance slowdown you should definitely look at this area. One of the possible solutions to tackle this problem is to reuse your proxies across your application threads, either implementing a singleton or a pool

from [Javi's blog on creating WCF proxy as singleton using Castle](http://javiercrespoalvez.com/2008/09/singleton-wcf-proxy.html). Can someone provide an implementation using Structuremap?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple with StructureMap, and even though you would need to do some testing this should work:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(
            x =>
            {
                x.For<GetFilesService.Service1Client>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(ctx =>
                    {
                        // Setup logic goes here
                        return new GetFilesService.Service1Client("NetTcpBinding_IService1", "net.tcp://localhost:8089/test");
                    });
            }
        );
```

The secret here is to use the Thread Local scope (`HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped`)

Then Resolve:

```
var client = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<GetFilesService.Service1Client>();
```

Comment: How do you make sure channel associated with ServiceClient is not faulted?